# How to judge the convergence of $\int _{1}^{\sqrt[]{3} }\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The definite integral has a discontinuity at the point $a=\sqrt[]{\frac{1+\sqrt[]{5} }{2} }. $ $$\int _{1}^{\sqrt[]{3} }\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
Had a try:
\begin{align}
I&=\int _{1}^{\sqrt[]{3} }\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\\  
&=\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx+\int_{a}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\\
\end{align}

I guess the integral is divergent but I can't prove how (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Consider what you obtain if you write the integrand as $a/(\sqrt 5 (x - a))$ plus a remainder.

Comment: Consider(just a try) set $x^2-\sqrt{x^2+1}=(x-a)f(x)$ $$lim_{x\to a}\frac{x-a}{(x-a)f(x)}=k\neq 0$$ , So $$\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$ and $$\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{x-a}dx$$ have same convergence and divergence. Thus, the integral is divergent

Comment: Correct, that's the limit comparison test. $1/(x^2 - \sqrt {x^2 + 1})$ and $1/(x - a)$ are negative and continuous on $[1, a)$, and $k \neq 0$ exists and is finite.